# Schema comparison between different db vendors

Tags: sql, database, comparison

I have to compare two schemas from different DB vendors, for example MySQL vs SQL server, is there a good comparison tool that can do that relatively easy?
I've been looking, but what I've found so far works only with schemas/databases from one vendor.

If somebody can suggest something it would be really helpful, thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly do you want to compare here between the two schemas?

Comment: In an ideal scenario everything should match, like tables, columns in the tables, indices, pk/fk etc., so that's my main target. Even the data should be the same, but a good start would be the aforementioned.

Comment: I think your question should focus on one thing, e.g. compare column names and types.  Asking for everything at once seems too broad (unless someone really knows of a tool which can do it already).  I'm thinking of querying `information_schema` on both databases.

Comment: You may be right, but there's a lot of tools online that claim to do that, so I was hoping if someone stumbled into the right one, since I haven't yet. :)